# Connection refused when deploying in cloud on kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, openshift

I am deploying kubernetes in Cloud and I'm trying to call another container inside the same pod through an API.

I am using `localhost` but also I treid with `127.0.0.1`. Also, I tried with the container's name.

```
2022/11/04 15:50:47 dial tcp [::1]:4245: connect: connection refused
2022/11/04 15:50:47 Successfully processed file.json file
2022/11/04 15:50:47 Get "http://localhost:4245/api/admin/projects/default": dial tcp [::1]:4245: connect: connection refused

panic: Get "http://localhost:4245/api/admin/projects/default": dial tcp [::1]:4245: connect: connection refused
goroutine 1 [running]:
log.Panic({0xc000119dc8?, 0xc000166000?, 0x6aaaea?})
/opt/app-root/src/sdk/go1.19.2/src/log/log.go:388 +0x65
main.StatusServer({0xc000020570?, 0x30?}, {0x0, 0x0})
/build/script.go:197 +0x1ee
main.ProcessData({0xc000020041, 0x15}, {0x0, 0x0}, {0xc00002000f?, 0x43ce05?})
/build/script.go:291 +0xa6
main.main()
/build/script.go:443 +0xc5
```

Any idea if I can call the container like that?

Comment: yes you can call containers in the same pod via localhost. If you need more help, you need to provide more info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get a connection refused means you reached localhost and it decided to refuse the connection.

This is most likly because nothing is listening on the port.

If it was a firewall issue the request would timeout.

You can check listening ports with command like:

```
netstat -an
```

If not installed maybe you can try it from the workernode where the pod is running.

Another method of testing is to use

```
curl http://127.0.0.1:4245
```

This will probably result in same connection refused.

Are you really sure the container is running in same pod?

Please check your deployment and service.

If you cant find the failure please come back with more information so it can be analysed.

Comment: I already figure it out. I had disabled SSL authentication and that was the issue. Also I fixed a typo in USERNAME variable.